# Best way to renew cookies?

Tags: php

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
    setcookie(
        "cookie",
        generateRandomString(),
        time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    );
} else {
    setcookie(
        "cookie",
        $_COOKIE['cookie'],
        time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    );
}
```

This is the first time I had to use cookies, and I would like to get your opinion on how the best and fastest way renew cookies

Comment: You can read this tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_http_setcookie.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to reset a cookie that has already been set. The following is enough to set the cookie. The cookie shall remain until the timestamp passes.

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {
     setcookie(
         "cookie",
         generateRandomString(),
         time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    );
}
```